# Laravel Inertia Form Validation Issue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, validation, inertiajs

I have added the ability to create and update service options. When submitting the create form it doesn't trigger the validation. Create and Edit are separate components which are effectively just wrappers around the form fields.

#### Create

```
 <script setup>
     import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
     import { client_route } from '@/helpers'
     import OptionForm from '@/Components/Service/OptionForm.vue';

     const props = defineProps({
         service: {
             type: Object
         }
     });

     const emit = defineEmits(['complete']);

     const form = useForm({
         name: '',
         type: null,
         help_text: null,
         price: 0,
         price_config: null,
         choices: null
     });

     const submit = () => {
         console.log('submit create', form);
         form.post(client_route('api.admin.service.option.store', {service: props.service.id}),
             {onSuccess: (res) => console.log('success', res), onError: (err) => console.log('error', err)}
         )
     }

 </script>

 <template>

     <form @submit.prevent="submit">
         <OptionForm :form="form" :header="'New Service Option'"/>
     </form>
 </template>
```

#### Edit

```
 <script setup>
     import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
     import { client_route } from '@/helpers'
     import OptionForm from '@/Components/Service/OptionForm.vue';

     const props = defineProps({
         service: {
             type: Object
         },
         option: {
             type: Object
         }
     });

     const emit = defineEmits(['complete']);

     const serviceOptionForm = useForm({
         name: props.option.name,
         type: props.option.type,
         help_text: props.option.help_text,
         price: props.option.price,
         price_config: props.option.price_config,
         choices: props.option.choices
     });

     const submit = () => {
         console.log('submit edit', serviceOptionForm);
         serviceOptionForm.patch(
             client_route('api.admin.service.option.update', {service: props.service.id, option: props.option.id}),
             {onSuccess: (res) => console.log('succ', res), onError: (err) => console.log('error', err)}
         )
     }
 </script>

 <template>

     <form @submit.prevent="submit">
         <OptionForm :form="serviceOptionForm" :option="option" :header="'Update Service Option'"/>
     </form>
 </template>
```

These both hit the same Form Request object

`public function store(StoreServiceOptionRequest $request`

`public function update(StoreServiceOptionRequest $request`

```
 class StoreServiceOptionRequest extends FormRequest
 {
     /**
      * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
      */
     public function authorize(): bool
     {
         return true;
     }

     /**
      * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
      *
      * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
      */
     public function rules(): array
     {
         return [
             'name' => 'required|string',
             'type' => 'required|string',
             'help_text' => 'nullable|string',
             'price' => 'nullable',
             'price_config' => 'nullable|string',
         ];
     }
 }
```

A breakdown of the requests: initialization of blank object for creating, submitting blank object, incorrectly getting success.
Then mapping existing object data, removing the name then submitting, and getting the expected "name missing" validation error.
[image: breakdown of requests]

I did notice that in the edit version it was an empty string instead of null so tried that for test purposes
[image: testing blank string]

For context both of these forms are in modals on a view page.

```
         <v-dialog width="500" v-model="showNewServiceOptionDialog">
             <CreateOption :service="service" @complete="showNewServiceOptionDialog = false"/>
         </v-dialog>

         <v-dialog width="500" v-model="showEditServiceOptionDialog">
             <EditOption :service="service" :option="option" @complete="showEditServiceOptionDialog = false"/>
         </v-dialog>
```